# Young adult sci fi book - two people from a spaceship stranded on a planet for a few years

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a young adult sci fi book, about a young woman with green eyes on a space ship who meets a man with white blond hair - both are later stranded on a planet for a few years - I think they have kids on the planet before they are rescued. I think book has "star" in the title

Comment: When did you read this? Was it in English?

Comment: I read it in the mid 90's but not sure when it was published, yep was in English

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/looking-for-a-book-wormhole-space-ship-crash-landing (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [The Fall of Angels](http://www.lemodesittjr.com/the-books/saga-recluce/fall-angels/) from L.E. Modesitt's "Saga of Recluse" books?

It's got your spaceship crash with stranded crew. Don't recall whether green eyes were a thing, and there's no rescue per se, but the man's white hair and the children they have are major themes.