# Looking for a book, wormhole, space ship Crash landing

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, wormhole

From what I remember of the book:

- A spaceship goes through a wormhole (I think) and crash lands on a planet
  They salvage what they can from the ship and build a castle on a mountain, cutting the stone with the lasers from the crashed ship
- The crew develop some sort of powers, the captain (She) seems to develop some sort of Precognition
- The planet's inhabitants where men rule and women are second class citizens
  Some women escape to the crew's castle so they can be equal citizens
- After they build the castle the crew fight the inhabitants the that came to attack them

**What is the name of this book?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fall of Angels, by L.E. Modesitt, Jr.

[image: Fall of Angels Cover]

Your memory is pretty good, although you're giving Nylan short shrift - that's okay, because the point of the book is partially that Nylan, as a man, gets shorter shrift than he deserves.

To shamelessly quote the [author's web page](http://www.lemodesittjr.com/the-books/saga-recluce/fall-angels/):

> Modesitt moves deep into Recluce’s past to chronicle the founding of
>   the Empire of the Legend, the almost mythological domain ruled by
>   woman warriors on the highland plateau of the continent of Candar. He
>   tells the story from the point of view of Nylan, the engineer and
>   builder whose job it is to raise a great tower on the plateau known as
>   the Roof of the World. Here the exiled women warriors will live and
>   survive to fulfill their destiny. Here a revolutionary new society
>   will be born
>
> . . . if Nylan can get the tower built and defenses in place before
>   the rulers of the lowland nations come with their armies to obliterate
>   them all. And if Nylan can learn to control the magical powers that
>   are growing within him.

It's the 6th book set in Recluce, albeit the earliest chronologically - it's the flashback to the foundational event that sets the stage upon which all the other books play.  It's the arrival of Order magic on a world of Chaos magic.